# How to create a view which negates its within codition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I have a view created as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ITEM_USAGE_V(LAST_USAGE_DATE, Item_Name, CODE) AS
   SELECT MAX (use_date) AS last_usage_date,
          COUNT (DISTINCT itnmed) AS Item_Name,
                bcde as code
   FROM (SELECT use_date, itnmed,bcde
             FROM item_usage_info iui
            WHERE EXISTS
                     (SELECT 1
                        FROM item_all
                       WHERE itnmed = iui.itnmed AND status = 1
                      ))
    group by bcde;
```

when i run the below query

```
select *
from ITEM_USAGE_V
where bcde='341232125421' and itnmed='dipos_container'
```

the behavior should be as below

```
SELECT 
     MAX (use_date) AS last_usage_date, 
     COUNT (DISTINCT itnmed) AS Item_Name, 
     bcde as code FROM 
         (SELECT use_date, 
                 itnmed,bcde 
           FROM  item_usage_info iui 
           WHERE EXISTS 
                 (SELECT 1 
                  FROM item_all 
                  WHERE itnmed = iui.itnmed 
                  AND status = 1 
                  AND itnmed <> iui.itnmed))  group by bcde
```

when the run query

```
select * from ITEM_USAGE_V where bcde='341232125421' and itnmed='dipos_container'
```

the behavior should be as original view.

How can i achieve this

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me - you say when you run one query you want one behaviour, and when you run the same query again you want a different behaviour - and that different behaviour includes an additional clause in the correlated join conditions which directly contradicts a previous join condition? `where itnmed = iui.itnmed ... and itnmed != iui.itnmed`... um, you can't have it both ways at the same time! N.B. for your exists query, you should alias the item_all table and all references to its columns

Comment: Where do you run the query with `bcde='341232125421' and itnmed='dipos_container'` ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please describe in detail the behavior you want. You are trying to show it with SQL, but the SQL isn't correct so we have no idea what results you want.

Comment: Also note: the second "SELECT 1 FROM item_all ..." won't ever return anything because it has two WHERE clauses that are opposites: "WHERE itnmed = iui.itnmed AND itnmed <> iui.itnmed".

Comment: actually i have a parser where the operator is is hard coded to equal (=), so when i call the view the query built is     bcde='341232125421' and itnmed='dipos_container' but i need the output to be     bcde='341232125421' and itnmed<>'dipos_container'

Comment: I really don't understand your requirement. Why don't simply create two separate views and use one or the other when required ? Or why don't use two separate queries ? Why do you need a "parser" ? It seems to me that you overcomplicate a very simple task instead of keeping it KISS --> see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: It *is* possible to force a query to behave completely different than intended, by using DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE like in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888050/oracle-select-returns-rows-but-select-count1-return-0).  However, for rewrite equivalency Oracle will consider your two queries to be identical.  You need to have more than just whitespace and case difference between the queries for that to work.