# Select count(*) returns 0 but select * returns 2 rows

Tags: sql, oracle

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888050/oracle-select-returns-rows-but-select-count1-return-0) with a full minimal example.

I have a simple select query (from a non-empty table) with only left joins. The last left join happens to be with an empty table.

The query returns 2 non-null rows as it should, but simply changing it to a count(*) query makes it return **0** as the count of rows.

The same SQL works properly on both MySQL and MSSQL (after fixing the PK syntax).

Full (re-runnable if uncomented) example:

```
-- DROP TABLE first;
-- DROP TABLE second;
-- DROP TABLE empty;

CREATE TABLE first (
  pk int,
  fk int
);
ALTER TABLE first
 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_first PRIMARY KEY (pk);

CREATE TABLE second (
  pk int
);
ALTER TABLE second
 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_second PRIMARY KEY (pk);

CREATE TABLE empty (
  pk int
);

ALTER TABLE first ADD CONSTRAINT FK_first FOREIGN KEY (fk)
 REFERENCES second (pk) ENABLE;

INSERT INTO second (pk)
  VALUES (5);
  
INSERT INTO first (pk, fk)
  VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO first (pk, fk)
  VALUES (2, 5);

SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM first
LEFT OUTER JOIN second
  ON (first.fk = second.pk)
LEFT OUTER JOIN empty
  ON (1 = 1);
```

The last query returns 0 on my machine, but changing the `count(*)` to just `*` makes it return **2** rows.

Can anyone reproduce this? My db_version is 11.2.0.2.

Explain plan seems to see the 2 rows that should be returned:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |          |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |          |     1 |    13 |            |          |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|          |     2 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    VIEW               |          |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | EMPTY    |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    BUFFER SORT        |          |     2 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     INDEX FULL SCAN   | PK_FIRST |     2 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

I don't know much about dynamic sampling, but if i `alter session set OPTIMIZER_DYNAMIC_SAMPLING=0;`, then the plan shows 82 rows in each step.

Removing the primary keys fixes the problem on Oracle, but that is hardly a proper solution.

Removing the join into the empty table also fixes the problem, but it is an outer join with tautological filter, so it should be a noop.

Is this actually the intended behavior on Oracle for some reason? Or is my server just bugged?
Both MSSQL and MySQL return 2 as the count.

**Edit: Round 2**

It was enough to add 2 more tables and the bug shows also in 11.2.0.4. Can anyone reproduce it on more current Oracle versions?

An online fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cf338/1).

```
CREATE TABLE first (
  pk int,
  fk int
);
ALTER TABLE first
 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_first PRIMARY KEY (pk);

CREATE TABLE second (
  pk int,
  fk int
);
ALTER TABLE second
 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_second PRIMARY KEY (pk);

CREATE TABLE third (
  pk int,
  fk int
);
ALTER TABLE third
 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_third PRIMARY KEY (pk);

CREATE TABLE fourth (
  pk int
);
ALTER TABLE fourth
 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_fourth PRIMARY KEY (pk);

CREATE TABLE empty (
  pk int
);

ALTER TABLE first ADD CONSTRAINT FK_first FOREIGN KEY (fk)
 REFERENCES second (pk) ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE second ADD CONSTRAINT FK_second FOREIGN KEY (fk)
 REFERENCES third (pk) ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE third ADD CONSTRAINT FK_third FOREIGN KEY (fk)
 REFERENCES fourth (pk) ENABLE;

INSERT INTO fourth (pk)
  VALUES (50);
  
INSERT INTO third (pk, fk)
  VALUES (10, 50);
INSERT INTO third (pk, fk)
  VALUES (11, 50);

INSERT INTO second (pk, fk)
  VALUES (5, 10);
INSERT INTO second (pk, fk)
  VALUES (6, 10);

INSERT INTO first (pk, fk)
  VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO first (pk, fk)
  VALUES (2, 5);

SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM first
LEFT OUTER JOIN second
  ON (first.fk = second.pk)
LEFT OUTER JOIN third
  ON (first.pk = third.pk)
LEFT OUTER JOIN fourth
  ON (third.fk = fourth.pk)
LEFT OUTER JOIN empty
  ON (1 = 1);
```

Anyway the consensus seems to be that this is a bug in obsolete Oracle releases.

Comment: In response to a comment on the linked question, changing the query to SELECT COUNT(1) OVER () returns 0 rows instantly.

Comment: [Works in Oracle 18](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07de98b13c733ff1f5a7d668c64b0cff) (and 12.1) - could very well be a bug in your unsupported (and no longer maintained) version.

Comment: Hah.. Just did the same.. @hwnn.. it really is broken on 11.2 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f91ac/1

Comment: Works fine with my dbms. I.e. count(*) returns 2.

Comment: @jarlh and what is your dbms?

Comment: @CaiusJard, no self-promotion here. ;-)

Comment: Just tried it on a second machine and it works correctly. db_version 11.2.0.4 - they fixed it quickly.

Comment: Could anyone test the new code on recent Oracle systems please? I can't make dbfiddle.uk work, says invalid character.

Comment: Second one [works in Oracle 18](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7b201f05269f361071f5e42cbe536ecd)

Comment: @JakubFojtik I've updated my answer with an additions about Update2 and hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11.2.0.2 is too old version (EOL already )and looks like it even has never been patched.

The obvious workaroud for your bug is the hint `no_query_transformation`, try:

```sql
SELECT--+ no_query_transformation
  COUNT(*)
FROM first
LEFT OUTER JOIN second
  ON (first.fk = second.pk)
LEFT OUTER JOIN empty
  ON (1 = 1);
```

**Update and addition:** you can just disable join elimination using hint NO_ELIMINATE_JOIN:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cf338/10

```sql
SELECT--+ NO_ELIMINATE_JOIN(second)
  COUNT(*)
FROM first
LEFT OUTER JOIN second
  ON (first.fk = second.pk)
LEFT OUTER JOIN empty e
  ON (1 = 1);
```

or  _optimizer_join_elimination_enabled:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cf338/10

```sql
    SELECT--+ opt_param('_optimizer_join_elimination_enabled' 'false')
      COUNT(*)
    FROM first
    LEFT OUTER JOIN second
      ON (first.fk = second.pk)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN third
      ON (first.pk = third.pk)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fourth
      ON (third.fk = fourth.pk)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN empty
      ON (1 = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is this usable in production though, since it disables optimizations? Or is there maybe a more specific hint that would have less perf impact? Could help people who cannot upgrade for whatever reason.

Comment: @JakubFojtik yes, of course, for example the most obvious in your case is `NO_OUTER_JOIN_TO_INNER`, but there are a lot of nuances. It would much better if you provide full query with full output of real execution plan using `dbms_xplan.display_cursor(..,..,'advanced')`

Comment: Thanks, the _optimizer_join_elimination_enabled works even on our older database v11.2.0.2, and seems specific enough to not disable too many optimizations.